# How to not suspend WiFi when closing laptop lid

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to figure out a workaround for the WiFi going into Airplane Mode whenever I shut the laptop lid.

I did change the config file in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` to, say,

```
wifi.powersave = 2
```

to no effect.

I have also gone into **gnome-tweaks** to turn off 'suspend when the laptop lid is closed'

to no effect.

I have also typed into the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action blank
```

to no effect.
What else can there be done?